# android : mail send using javamail smtp tls is not getting saved in sent folder of icloud account

Tags: android, ssl, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am using javamail for a mail client application. I have added an iCloud account with SMTP TLS for outgoing, and imap for incoming

```
acct.iIncomingHostType = Constants.HOSTTYPE_IMAP;
acct.sIncomingHost = "imap.mail.me.com";
acct.sIncomingHostPort = "993";
acct.iIncomingHostEncryption = Constants.ENCRYPT_SSL;

acct.sOutgoingHost = "smtp.mail.me.com";
acct.sOutgoingHostPort = "587";
acct.iOutgoingHostEncryption = Constants.ENCRYPT_TLS;
acct.bOutgoingHostSPALogin = false;
```

Now when I send a mail, it's reaching the recipient mailbox - be it gmail or outlook etc, but the mail sent is not coming in the sent folder of my iCloud account.

Code looks as below

```
Properties props = new Properties();
            /// sProtocol is "smtp"
            props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");

            props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", sProtocol);
            props.setProperty("mail.host", acct.sOutgoingHost);
            props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol + ".port",
                    acct.sOutgoingHostPort);
            props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol + ".socketFactory.port",
                    acct.sOutgoingHostPort);
            props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol + ".timeout", "30000");
            props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol + ".connectiontimeout",
                    "30000");


            props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol + ".auth", "true");

            props.setProperty("mail.debug.auth", "true");


            props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol + ".sasl.enable", "true");



                props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol + ".starttls.enable",
                        "true");
                props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol + ".ssl.trust", "*");

                props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol
                        + ".ssl.socketFactory.class",
                        "com.isaacdanielgroup.sempostmark.SEMPSSLSocketFactory");
                props.setProperty("mail." + sProtocol
                        + ".ssl.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you might be able to simplify your program by [getting rid of all the socket factory stuff](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

There's no magic that causes sent messages to be added to the Sent folder.  If you want a copy of the message there, you need to put it there yourself.  See the [msgsend.java sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples) for an example.

Comment: You are right . For gmail it is automaticaaly saved by server . So it was working for gmial by default. For yahho and icloud i had to append the message to send folder